# Angular 4 привязка к изменению свойств в сервисе

Tags: angular4

Нужно сделать так что бы при изменение определенного свойства в сервисе выполнялсь определенная функция в другом компоненте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При изменении свойства в сервисе нужно эмитить ивент.
В компоненте подписаться на этот ивент и выполнять функцию. 
Подробности см. здесь https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter